# How do I delete sources.list.d and add/install it again?

Tags: apt, ppa, software-sources

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d` contains

```
jonathonf-ubuntu-python-3_6-xenial.list
jonathonf-ubuntu-python-3_6-xenial.list.save
notepadqq-team-ubuntu-notepadqq-xenial.list
notepadqq-team-ubuntu-notepadqq-xenial.list.save
oracle-vbox.list
oracle-vbox.list.save
owncloud.list
owncloud.list.save
ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
webcamstudio-ubuntu-webcamstudio-stable-xenial.list
webcamstudio-ubuntu-webcamstudio-stable-xenial.list.save
webupd8team-ubuntu-atom-xenial.list
webupd8team-ubuntu-atom-xenial.list.save
webupd8team-ubuntu-tor-browser-xenial.list
webupd8team-ubuntu-tor-browser-xenial.list.save
yannubuntu-ubuntu-boot-repair-xenial.list
yannubuntu-ubuntu-boot-repair-xenial.list.save
```

Comment: What do you mean install it again? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Im getting error for each and every thing in that folder

Comment: [edit] your question with the full output of `sudo apt update`, formatted as code with the `{}` button

Comment: Error opening "XXXXX" permisson denied...The list of sources couldnt be read

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can remove all custom repositories by running

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Isn't it necesarry to keep them?

Comment: It is not necessary. Something is wrong with these repos. You can always add them, if you need additional software from a PPA.